# ActionLink Not Differentiating Two Different Similar Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, routes

I have two routes:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "route1",
        "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/NotTest/{notParam}/{param4}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            new[] { "Controllers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "route2",
            "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/Test/{param3}/{param4}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                new[] { "Controllers" });
```

Where NotTest and Test are both static strings in the url and the only thing that differentiates the two routes is notParam and param3 are different strings. I can link to route2 fine using actionlink but anytime I try to link to route1 I am getting a get request to my controller with a bunch of parameters laid out instead of having it link using the actual route. With RouteLink I don't even get a URL...

Is there something else I should be doing to differentiate between the two routes?

The links I have are something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Example Data", "Action", "Controller", new {param1= Model.Data, param2, param3, notParam, param4}, new { id = "columnsID" })
```

Comment: "Different Similar"? Is that like "Pretty Ugly"? Sorry had to do say something. What if you move `Route 2` mapped route above `Route 1` in your `RouteConfig` is the opposite true with your `ActionLink`?

Comment: if i move route 2 above route 1 and use RouteLink neither work...if i use actionlink it is the same as if i didn't move the routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Html.RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method here:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Example Data", 
                "route1",
                new 
                { 
                    action = "Action",
                    controller = "Controller"
                    /*other route values*/
                 })
```

Comment: if i use RouteLink and link to route2 I get an empty anchor tag, but the route for route1 works. thoughts?

Comment: @BenNelson Did you state all route values? Only the last parameters are optional in MVC routes.

Comment: ya all the routes associated with these actions are listed

Comment: @BenNelson Can you share how you used it with route2?

Comment: AH! You were right, your answer is correct. I had one property that was null that I was unaware of that was causing the route to not be generated. Here, have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to build this link by directly referencing the route:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("route1", new { httproute = "", controller = "Controller", action = "Action", param1 = param1, param2 = param2, notParam = notParam, param4 = param4 })">Your Link</a>

<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("route2", new { httproute = "", controller = "Controller", action = "Action", param1 = param1, param2 = param2, param3 = param3, param4 = param4 })">Your Link</a>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the problem was the same as described above. You must make sure to specify all route parameters. `Url.RouteUrl` essentially works the same as `Html.RouteLink` except it provides only the Url and doesn't build the entire link for you.